# Keycloak - WhoamI request fails with 403

Tags: docker, keycloak

I have tried solving this problem for days now and I can't figure out how.

I have created a docker instance with keycloak using:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 --name keycloak --net keycloak-network -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin -e KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL="https://myurl.com/auth" -e KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL=DEBUG --env JAVA_OPTS="-Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0" jboss/keycloak
```

When I open `https://myurl.com` and click on Administration Console, it correctly prompts the login credentials. But, once I click "login" it gives me a white page. In the Chrome's debugger it says that the request to `/auth/admin/master/console/whoami` fails with `403`. Which is weird, because all requests prior to that one, including the token request, work fine.

However, If I recreate the docker instance with the same command EXCEPT the `KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL` part, and access the docker with a local address (192.168.1.X) it works just fine.

I enabled the logging and they both look the same except that the one with the url set doesn't have the following line (and other lines from then on):

```
 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.AdminConsole] (default task-1) setting up realm access for a master realm user
```

But this doesn't allow me to use my public address, outside my organization.
What am I missing?

Note: I have replaced the URLs with a fake one for obvious security issues.

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: tried to reproduce your example - but failed. just removed `--net keycloak-network` and changed url to `http://` and `-p 80:8080`. no problem while login in via the domain (and hosts entry set). It seems you are using something (reverseProxy?) in front of keycloak. maybe this causes the issue. can you add more infos about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been a while since I asked this but this might be useful to someone: I finally got to the issue: the server/proxy was for some reason blocking the `Authentication` header, and therefore it was always giving the 403 code.

Comment: Hello,

I am facing a similar issue, with keycloak + nginx. What changes did you do to fix this issue.